# Javascript vuejs component in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, components, vuejs2

I have a v-for loop in vuejs that displays a component on each iteration.  This is an autocomplete component that searches and displays product names when a user types in the input box.

I have a `@change="setProduct"` attribute on each component that correctly calls my `setProduct` method in my parent component.

But how can I know which of component was updated? All thats passed to the setProduct method is the details of the product that was emitted, but I don't know which component emitted the event to know which line to update.

---

Here is some relevant code:
This is in the parent component

```
<template>
    <div class="row" v-for="line, i in invoice.InvoiceLines">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <auto-complete :list="productList" :value="line.Product.name"  @change="setProduct"></auto-complete>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            invoice:{},
            productList:[]
        },
    }
    methods:{
        setProduct(product){
           //product has the details of the new product that was selected. But I don't know which invoice line it is referring to. 
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

The  component responds to a user clicking a selection in a dropdown, and then issues $emit('change', product);

The  component has no knowledge of the parent component, so it doesn't know which invoice line it refers to. I could pass the index into the child component and then pass it back out, but that seems anti-pattern for vue.

Maybe there is an easier way for me to go about this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to pass an id of product or index in `setProduct ` or some other way to identify, Can you please add some relevant code to give us more idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `v-for`, so you can actually retrieve the `index` of the items in `invoice.InvoiceLines` and you can pass whatever your want into `setProduct`:

```
<template>
    <div class="row" v-for="(line, i) in invoice.InvoiceLines">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <auto-complete 
                :list="productList" 
                :value="line.Product.name"  
                @change="setProduct(line, i, $event)"></auto-complete>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
methods: {
    setProduct(product, index, event){
       // product - the 'line' responsible in invoice.InvoiceLines
       // index - the index of line in invoice.InvoiceLines
       // event - the event object
    },
}
```